# What is the best/idioms way in python to handle series of function check

Tags: python, if-statement, idioms

I would like to ask what's the best/idioms way in python to handle this type of code logic.

```
list_a = []

def func_a():
  if some check not pass
     return False

  # check pass
  add some stuff to list_a and return True

def func_b():
  if some check not pass
     return False

  # check pass
  add some stuff to list_a and return True

def func_c():
  if some check not pass
     return False

  # check pass
  add some stuff to list_a and return True

def apply_function():
  if fun_a():
     return list_a
  if fun_b():
     return list_a
  if fun_c():
     return list_a
  ...

  return list_a   #empty list
```

If there are more than 10 functions need to check in `apply_function()`, is there any better way to handle?

This maybe work for me

```
If funcA() or funcB() or funcC():
  return list_a

return list_a
```

Does `any()` can be use in this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: It is more troubling that you add stuff to `list_a`, since it is a list out of outer scope, this introduces a concept of state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't alter a global. Have your function *return* a list or raise an exception if the check failed. That way you can just return the result of the function, or if an exception was raised, continue on to the next.

```
def func_a():
    if some check not pass
        raise ValueError('....')

    # check pass
    return [some, list]

# further functions that apply the same pattern.

def apply_function():
    for f in (func_a, func_b, func_c):
        try:
            return f()
        except ValueError:
            # check didn't pass, continue on to the next
            pass
```

Exceptions are the ideal method here to signal that a check failed, the function is telling the caller that it *can't* return a result because the conditions to do so have not been met. You can trust the return value to be correct if no exceptions occurred.

Note that functions are just objects, so given their names you can put them in a sequence and iterate over them. You can use some register to add more functions to try to a global list, too.

Comment: Thank you. The program was originally for exhaustive all cases, and func_b will check more loose than func_a and check different cases.